# Need to recover files deleted from *.gho with Ghost explorer

Tags: norton-ghost

I accidentally deleted some folders from GHO image (of ntfs drive) which was created with Symatec Ghost 11.5.
I opened gho image with Ghost image explorer and deleted few folders. How to recover them?

I tried to restore image and tried to recover folders with Recuva and other recovery programs. None of these programs were able to help me. Folders were visible, however, contents of the files were empty or filled with "zzzzz". Files in these folders are doc, pdf, xls.

When I deleted folder, the size of the GHO image  doesnt change, however the properties of the image states that there are 700 patched files. How to restore these files ?

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am with soandos's comment. You are not going to be able to recover it from within the file. Your only chance is if you have some software, like File Scavenger 3.0, that can find a deleted/overwritten copy of the ghost image file on the disk. Restore that, and you may have a chance...but probably a slim one. In the meantime, stop using the disk if possible, because you are likely to overwrite critical data, necessary to even try what I suggested.

Comment: Sad to hear, because some time passed, while files were reported accidentally deleted :/